# Given an ID from one service, get data from other JSON, with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new in AngularJs and I'm trying to get data from 2 different JSON returning services.
I have a list, obtained from one service, where I'm showing the user ID.
This is working, but what I need is, given that user ID, obtain the user's first name and last name from the other JSON.
How can I do it? Any help is welcome.

This is the AngularJs (1.6) controller:

```
controller('myReservations',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.reserve = [];
    $scope.sId = s;
    $http.get('/reserve/').then(
        function(response){
            $scope.reserve = response.data.description;
        },
        function(response){
            console.log(response.statusText);
        }
    );
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="reservationsList" ng-controller="myReservations">
    <li ng-repeat="res in reserve | filter: {ideventroom: sId}">
        User: {{res.iduser}} <br>
        First name: <!-- Here goes the first name --><br>
        Last name: <!-- Here goes the last name -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the services are returning the following JSON.
In "/reserve/" I get:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "description": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ideventroom": 3,
        "iduser": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "ideventroom": 3,
        "iduser": 1
    }
    ]
}
```

In "/user/2" I get:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "description": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Smith",
            "email": "johnny@smithy.co",
            "phone": "11111111"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain a second then function onto your first one. Inside that function, you can make your other http request using your now available userid.